# Extract part of an url using a bookmarklet or similar (e.g. firefox addon)

Tags: url, gmail, firefox-addon, clipboard, bookmarklet

Does anybody know of a bookmarklet or firefox addon that let's you extract part of an url.

Specifically I want to extract the message id from a gmail conversation.
Every message in gmail has a unique ID. The url may look like this: https://mail.google.com/a/domain.com/#all/1251b8f40722a3c2

What I want, is to be able to extract the last 16 characters (the "1251b8f40722a3c2" part) from the url and have it copied to the clipboard automatically.

A bookmarklet would be preferred (compatibility), but a firefox addon is also okay.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot all about this question.
I got this answer from someone, I can't remember who. But maybe it will help someone else in my situation.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20theSnippedURL=location.href.match(/([0-9]|[a-f]){16}/g);if(theSnippedURL){var%20url=prompt(%22Copy%20the%20extracted%20ID%20below.%22,theSnippedURL);}else{alert(%22Couldn't%20find%20conversation%20ID.%22);}})();
```

This javascript can be used in a [bookmarklet like this](http://javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20theSnippedURL=location.href.match(/([0-9]|[a-f])%7B16%7D/g);if(theSnippedURL)%7Bvar%20url=prompt(%22Copy%20the%20extracted%20ID%20below.%22,theSnippedURL);%7Delse%7Balert(%22Couldn't%20find%20conversation%20ID.%22);%7D%7D)();). It extracts the message ID from Gmail, and shows it in a popup box. Unfortunatly it doesn't copy the ID to the clipboard, but you can just copy it from the popup, so that's ok.